# How to create a universal storyboard for universal app in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

How can I create a universal app in iOS with Storyboard?

Xcode - > File -> New -> Project -> Single View Application -> Universal App.The list of files that are autogenerated are present in the below screenshot :

[image]

Can I remove any storyboard and make a universal storyboard for iPads and iPhones?

Answer (score 1):

Just Delete the `iPad Storyboard`, Go to `Supporting files->ProjectName-Info.plist->Main storyboard file base name(iPad)` delete that as well. Now Run your app with `iPad` option in `Main Interface`, You can use for both `iPhone` and `iPad`. It may not work properly as the screen sizes of both devices are very different. I would suggest to use separate `storyboards`.

Comment: By putting a label in the center of the xib, in case of iPad, the label is not appearing in the center of that device.

Comment: @suhit: If you use "autolayouting" properly, your sizes will be layouted and you will have correct sizes.

Comment: With Xcode 6 there is no need to for separate storyboards, using size classes and storyboards it's possible to use it for iPhone and iPad